# Kubuntu cant access Windows 11 NVMe even when secure boot and fast boot disabled in bios and also in windows 11 disabled fast boot, Bitlocker wasnt ON

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, nvme

Kubuntu cant access Windows 11 NVMe drive even when secure boot and fast boot disabled in bios and also in windows 11 disabled fast boot, Bitlocker wasnt ON

See screenshot

[image]

After in Bios disabling secure boot then disk in windows got new icon

[image]

Bitlocker shows its not on

[image]

**UPDATE**

In Windows settings showing bitlocker hasnt finished setting up, but in middle. Now it should be off.
[image]

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution. If problems to mount a partition on the drive(s), see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) -- Which version of Kubuntu? What computer (brand name and model)?

Comment: I once came across a laptop that came bitlocker enabled from the factory.

Comment: @sudodus well turns out bitlocker can be on but without saved key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In control panel Bitlocker shows its off.
[image]

in windows settings Privacy & Security category Device encryption showing bitlocker is on.

In setting page was able to turn off and then it was not semi-on anymore, just few minutes decrypting and installing Kubuntu

[image]

Comment: +1+1; Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Comment: @user68186 yes, in setting page was able to turn off and then it was not semi-on anymore, just few minutes decrypting and installing Kubuntu

Comment: @user68186 what missing? Added sentence that its in windows settings Privacy & Security category Device encryption